# Breeze + Knockout bindings in graph collections

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm having trouble saving updates to an existing data graph in Breezejs using Knockoutjs bindings.

I began with John Papa's SPA using HotTowel & Durandal.

The symptoms are that I'm able to save updates to the physician record if the update is a simple property of the physician.  However, if I add a new element in one of the collections contained in the physician I can save the collection element but it comes to the server and is saved to the database but with null properties and without a reference to the physician.  I'm using Specialty as an example but i'm seeing the same behavior with any collection in the Physician record that I add an item to.  The added item comes up to the server with nulls in all the properties.

The physician graph displays fine on the page and I'm able to associate drop-downs fine with the appropriate values for the specific fields where appropriate.  Checkboxes etc. also show appropriate values.

Here's a segment of HTML that I'm using:

```
<div id="physGraph" class="span10" data-bind="with: currentPhysician()[0]">
    <!-- more stuff here -->
    <div id="physSpecialties" class="span8">
      <span class="span8">Physician Specialties<i class="icon-plus-sign" title="Add new specialty to physician" data-bind="click: $parents[0].addSpecialtyToPhysician"></i></span>
      <div class="span8 table-bordered" data-bind="foreach: physicianSpecialties">
        <div class="span8">
          <span data-bind="text: specialty().name()"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="span7  table-bordered">
          <i class="icon-remove-sign" title="Remove specialty from physician list" data-bind="click: $parents[1].removeSpecialtyFromPhysician"></i>
          <select data-bind="options: $parents[1].specialties(), optionsText: 'name', value: specialty()"></select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more stuff here -->
 </div> <!-- end with: currentPhysician()[0]
```

Here's how I'm getting the physician:

```
define([services/datacontext', 'viewmodels/physList'], function (datacontext, physListVm) {
  var initialized = false;
  var physNotes = ko.observableArray();
  var currentPhysician = ko.observable();
  var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Physician Edit',
    currentPhysician: currentPhysician,
    addSpecialtyToPhysician: addSpecialtyToPhysician,
    save: save,
    // more code in here
  }

  // internal functions for physDetailEdit
   function activate() {
    initLookups();
    var physIdSelectedFromList = physListVm.selectedPhys().id();
    return getPhysicianDetail(physIdSelectedFromList);
  }

  function getPhysicianDetail(requestedPhysId) {
    var promise = datacontext.getPhysicianDetails(requestedPhysId, currentPhysician);
    return promise;
  }
  more code in here
}
```

Here's how I'm adding the Specialty:

```
  function addSpecialtyToPhysician(item, event) {
    var newItem = datacontext.createSpecialty();
    item.physicianSpecialties.push(newItem);
    // I've also tried it like this -- > currentPhysician()[0].physicianSpecialties.push(newItem);
  }
```

Here's how I'm saving the record:

```
  function save() {
    return datacontext.saveChanges();
  }
```

Here's the codeFirst description of these two items:

```
  public class Physician
  {
    public Physician()
    {
      PhysicianSpecialties = new List<PhysicianSpecialty>();
      PhysicianPayers = new List<PhysicianPayer>();
      IncentivePrograms = new List<PhysicianIncentiveDetail>();
      PhysicianNotes = new List<Note>();
      PhysInOrgs = new List<PhysInOrg>();
      Memberships = new List<Membership>();
    }
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Person ContactInfo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhysicianIncentiveDetail> IncentivePrograms { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhysicianPayer> PhysicianPayers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhysicianSpecialty> PhysicianSpecialties { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Note> PhysicianNotes { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PhysInOrg> PhysInOrgs { get; set; }
    public string Dea { get; set; }
    public string Npi { get; set; }
    public string Tin { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public string MedLicenseNbr { get; set; }
    public string MedLicenseState { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MedLicenseRecertDate { get; set; }
    public EMRSystem EmrSystem { get; set; }
    public int ImportBatchId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPcp { get; set; }
    public bool SoloPractitioner { get; set; }
    public bool PartOfHospital { get; set; }
  }

  public class PhysicianSpecialty
  {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Physician Physician { get; set; }
    public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
  }
```

What I get when I save is:

```
Id  IsPrimary   Physician_Id    Specialty_Id
21  0           NULL            NULL
```

I'm assuming that by adding a specialty to the Physician graph Breeze will automatically insert the physician ID and the selected specialty from the drop-down which appears on the page when I push the specialty onto the currentPhysician()[0].

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Looking into this via offline email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from Ward Bell.  Needless to say, it works and I'm saved!

The problem was simplified to a single collection in the physician record: Specialties.  I've expanded the solution to all the other collections.

EF Model

Your PhysicianSpecialty.cs class was defined like this:

```
public class PhysicianSpecialty
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Physician Physician { get; set; }
  public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }
  public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

You’re missing the foreign keys (FKs) that support the associations, Physician and Specialty.  Breeze requires FKs when you want it to automatically maintain the associations for you.

Also, without metadata to describe the FKs, Breeze.NET did not know how to set the EF-generated Physician_Id and Specialty_Id columns.

I redefined it like so, with public and explicit foreign keys

```
public class PhysicianSpecialty
{
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }
  public Int32 PhysicianId { get; set; }
  public Int32 SpecialtyId { get; set; }
  public Physician Physician { get; set; }
  public Specialty Specialty { get; set; }
  public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}
```

When EF rebuilds the table, it now has PhysicianId and SpecialtyId columns. I choose those names because I like them better than names with underscores and they happen to fit EF’s conventions (It’s possible that the underscored names would too; I don’t remember).

Now those FK properties will be set when you assign the associations in BreezeJS client and everything flows through to the server.

Except you have two other problems.
Combobox KO binding

The following original HTML line in details.js has an incorrect KO binding:

```
  <select data-bind="options: $parent.specialties(), optionsText: 'name', value: specialty()"></select>
```

What you want is this:

```
  <select data-bind="options: $parent.specialties, optionsText: 'name', value: specialty" />
```

The critical difference is in the value binding; you can’t have those parentheses after specialty.

I cannot explain why. My Knockout isn’t good enough. I’m actually surprised in this case because I didn’t think extra parens hurt. Apparently they do.  Btw, you absolutely must have parens for the intermediate values in a path as in

```
  data-bind="foreach: phys().physicianSpecialties"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your data is saving partially so not sure whether this has any bearing at all with your issue but I faced a problem with the Hot Towel Template and breeze. For some reason the breeze source in the template is very different even after updating via nuget. Try downloading from breejejs and replacing the source. If it doesn't work you are no worse off. I posted my issue earlier

[Errors when using Breeze with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533508/errors-when-using-breeze-with-ef)

Comment: Hi Thanks.  I've notice that too and updated Breeze via Nuget and am up to 1.3.3.  Still the problem persists.  I've recruited IdeaBlade to help.  I'll post the solution when we find it.