# Errors when using Breeze with EF

Tags: breeze

I am using breezejs with EF. My Web API is returning an "object" consisting of properties from a number of linked entities which I use to bind to a grid. I will need to update some of the properties later and I want to cache the data , hence breeze. I am using the noDB sample to create a custom Entity.

The first problem is that breeze seems to expect a property called name to be passed in the addEntityType method or it throws an error The 'structuralTypeName' parameter  must be a 'string'.

The second problem is the call to structuralType._fixup in breeze on line 4742 seems to be throwing the following error Object # has no method '_fixup' though I can see the function exists.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong in the code below ? The error is in the addEntityType call.

```
manager.metadataStore.addEntityType({
            name: "Transcription", shortName: "Transcription", namespace: "Etrans.Data.Models", autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                audio: { dataType: DataType.String }, clientID: { dataType: DataType.Int32 }, clientName: { dataType: DataType.String },
                clinicianfirstname: { dataType: DataType.String }, clinicianlastname: { dataType: DataType.String }, Notes: { dataType: DataType.String },
                status: { dataType: DataType.String }, transcriptionid: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isPartOfKey: true }, user: { dataType: DataType.String }
            }

        });
        manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor("Transcription", null, customReportFields);
```

On the server side I have the data layer in a project called Etrans.Data. The web API invokes a repository which queries the data layer. In this instance it is querying an Entity called Transcription (Etrans.Data.Models.Transcription) and a number of linked entities.

Answer (score 2):

@shai - I regret the confusion you encountered which appears to be a consequence of the evolution of the BreezeJS client metadata definition API. But I do not fully understand your recommendation.

The HotTowel template and HT NuGet package(s) do depend upon an older version of the BreezeJS NuGet package which may have had an `addEntityType` method that has since changed (I haven't looked). I'll work with John Papa to get the HT stuff updated.

But I don't understand what you're telling people to do. The HT templates work as delivered if you stay within the boundaries of their then-official-capabilities. FWIW, client-side metadata definition was in beta at the time and we said that its API was likely to change. It is still a work in progress.

Updating an app to the latest versions of dependent packages will change some things of course. That is why one would upgrade.

Are you saying that there is a continuing problem *after you update* to the latest Breeze NuGet packages? Are you pointing to some discrepancy between the latest Breeze NuGet packages (1.3.3 as I write) and the latest source in GitHub. There is always some discrepancy there - BreezeJS on GitHub always holds our latest ideas ... many of which will change and none of them approved for development use. I would advise people to s[tick with official releases](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download).

Are you telling folks they shouldn't use HotTowel? Why? The problem you encountered is not in a mainstream feature (it's not even an official feature of HT).

OTOH, I both understand and fully agree with the recommendation to upgrade all HT dependent packages (including Durandal and Toastr as well as Breeze) to latest versions.

Thanks for hanging in there with us.

Comment: @ward- I used the Hot Towel template and did an upgrade to the latest breeze package via nuget and then encountered this problem. I then downloaded the latest source code from git hub and the code base for breeze was different.Hence my recommendation to grab latest source code from respective sources. Nowhere have I stated that Breeze or Hot towel template should not be used. On the contrary I am a staunch supporter of both and highly recommend them.

Comment: Glad to hear your enthusiasm for HT is undiminished. I'm really surprised that you're finding a difference between GitHub and the current v.1.3.3 NuGet *w/r/t `addEntityType`* ... because I don't see it. I just pasted Jay's example (with `shortName` in place of `name`) into a pure 1.3.3 project and did not get an exception. I'd like to see an example that explains why you think people should pull from GitHub rather than use the v 1.3.3 NuGet pkg. That shouldn't be the case. If it is, we need to fix it pronto.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, Breeze throws an error with this message on your call to addEntityType:

```
Error configuring an instance of 'EntityType'. Unknown property: 'name'.
```

Basically "name" is not a valid configuration parameter to the addEntityType call. So eliminating your 'name' property, which isn't needed because breeze builds it up out of the *shortName* and the *namespace*, your code becomes:

```
manager.metadataStore.addEntityType({
        shortName: "Transcription",
        namespace: "Etrans.Data.Models",
        autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
        dataProperties: {
            audio: { dataType: DataType.String },
            clientID: { dataType: DataType.Int32 },
            clientName: { dataType: DataType.String },
            clinicianfirstname: { dataType: DataType.String },
            clinicianlastname: { dataType: DataType.String },
            Notes: { dataType: DataType.String },
            status: { dataType: DataType.String },
            transcriptionid: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isPartOfKey: true },
            user: { dataType: DataType.String }
        }
    });
```

which runs just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: DANG! I just confirmed that myself :-)  You're too fast, Jay

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys. As I mentioned in my query , if I do not use the "name" parameter and just use the "shortName" parameter, breeze throws the following error - The 'structuralTypeName' parameter  must be a 'string'. It hits the following line 4724 . The structuralType seems to be the object being passed. As you can see it is looking for a name property which doesn't exist.

 
        proto.addEntityType = function (structuralType) {
            if (this.getEntityType(structuralType.name, true)) {
                var xxx = 7;
            }

Comment: I think that you are not running the latest version of Breeze or have not refreshed your cache. We ran the exact code that you mentioned without a problem on Breeze v 1.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

**TO ALL THOSE USING THE HOT TOWEL TEMPLATE... SUGGEST GRABBING THE LATEST BREEZE CODE DIRECTLY AND NOT USE THE NUGET UPDATE ...AS ON 15/05/2013**

Damn..I just wasted a day on this. The nuget package source and the package available from breezejs.com seem to be very different.I downloaded the latest source from breezejs and the lines I mentioned in my earlier comment don't exist as a matter of fact the whole addEntityType function is different... there is no structuralType.name!! I did use nuget to update to the latest stable source. Not sure whether this is from the hot towel template or from nuget.

Comment: I do not fully understand. The HotTowel template and nuget packages do refer to an older version of BreezeJS which may have had the now-non-existent `structuralType.name` property (client-side metadata definition was in beta at the time and we said the API was subject to change).